# I'm having an issue with Passport when my React and Node servers are different (Firebase), but no issue when they are the same (Heroku)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, passport.js

I've deployed my React app using `heroku` and authentication works fine with Passport, but when I used Firebase Hosting and Functions I've ran into some issues that I can't resolve.
Logging in on my app refreshes the page which calls a `useEffect` hook that checks to see if a user is logged in

```
const handleAdminLogin = async (username, password, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await ADMIN.login(username, password).then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        console.log(res);
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    ADMIN.getUser().then((res) => {
      console.log("success");
      if (res) {
        setUser({
          id: res.data.id,
          loggedIn: true,
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

The server sends status 200 so it is receiving the request with no errors

```
login: function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (!user) res.sendStatus(401);
      else {
        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.sendStatus(200);
        });
      }
    })(req, res, next);
  },
```

But that's where it stops. The function getUser gets no response.
I know I'm not handling errors properly in this scenario, so advice on that might help as well.

```
getUser: function (req, res) {
    if (req.user) {
      User.findOne({ username: req.user.username }).then((dbUser) => {
        res.send({
          id: dbUser._id,
          username: dbUser.username,
        });
      });
    }
  },
```

I believe my axios calls have the corrects headers:

```
const URL = "https://us-central1-foothill-fitness.cloudfunctions.net/app";

const headers = {
  "Access-Control-Allow_Origin": "https://foothillfitness.com",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};

export default {
  // Gets user info
  getUser: function () {
    return axios.get(
      `${URL}/admin/user`,
      { withCredentials: true },
      { headers: headers }
    );
  },

  // Log the user in
  login: function (username, password) {
    return axios.post(
      `${URL}/admin/user/login`,
      { username, password },
      { withCredentials: true },
      { headers: headers }
    );
  },
```

My passport middleware could also be causing a problem, but when running the server locally I got no errors

```
module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
    new localStrategy((username, password, done) => {
      User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) return done(null, false);
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (result === true) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false);
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
    cb(null, user.id);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: id }, (err, user) => {
      const userInformation = {
        username: user.username,
      };
      cb(err, userInformation);
    });
  });
};
```

And some server side code that I put in to try to rid myself of some CORS errors:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000", // "https://foothillfitness.com", // <-- location of the react app were connecting to
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use("*", function (req, res, next) {
  // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://foothillfitness.com");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
});

// enable pre-flight
app.options("*", cors());
```

After about 30 seconds or so the console pops up with this error as well:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://us-central1-foothill-fitness.cloudfunctions.net/app/admin/user'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Which I don't quite understand since I included the header in my code.

Any help with this would be much appreciated, as I have been losing my mind over this. I can provide more detail if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the headers sent using axios. there's an underscore in Access-Control-**Allow_Origin**. Change this to a dash, see if this solves the issue.

regarding the error handling, you can add `.catch` and `else`, something like this:

```js
getUser: function (req, res) {
    if (req.user) {
      User.findOne({ username: req.user.username }).then((dbUser) => {
        res.send({
          id: dbUser._id,
          username: dbUser.username,
        });
      }).catch(err => {
          throw new Error(err)
      });
    } else {
        throw new Error("No user provided")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response on that! Unfortunately it did not solve my issue though. I am receiving a status code 500 in the console now due to the added error handling.

Comment: Can you share the error? If it's from the `.catch` the issue is with the connection to mongodb

Comment: It's a new error so it's likely that is the case                                        
  `createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)`                                                                   However I have other calls that are working. just either Passport isn't working properly how I have it set up or this specific call isn't working properly.

Comment: Here's another error that pops up `xhr.js:177 GET https://us-central1-foothill-fitness.cloudfunctions.net/app/admin/user 500`

Comment: I was trying to reproduce this but failed. Check your connection with your mongodb

Comment: I'll keep trying, thank you for the help though.